# [GAE][NDB] Filter using property method

Tags: google-app-engine, datetime, app-engine-ndb

I have a collection of reservations.
The model for a Reservation includes dt, a datetime object.
I would like to be able to query for Reservations but filter based on the date alone, not including time.
So what I tried to do was: (assuming I have a datetime.date object called date)

```
Reservation.query().filter(Reservation.dt.date() == date).get()
```

I get an error that the DateTime object does not have a date attribute. I understand where the error is coming from, as in I can't use Reservation.dt.date(), but I fail to find an easy way to do this. I had to do some hacky inefficient method to do what I want and was wondering if there's some easier way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to either query for between the date at 00:00 and the next day at 00:00 (two filters on your query, one >= one <=), or store a separate property that contains just the date part of the datetime.

Comment: Thanks, I did just that.

Comment: I suggest using ComputedProperty: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed

Comment: Unfortunately, it's currently not possible to have a ComputedProperty produce a 'date' value.